# How to extra data from the app or file using google appmaker

Tags: google-apps, google-app-maker

I just began to learn the Google App Maker and had tons of the questions. Now i just used the template of Document Approval.

I have the following questions:

1. Could you recommend some learning materials for App Maker?
2. It seems that the there was no separated physical database for the app. How could I extra the data from the database?
3. How could I monitor the requests going somewhere?

Your guidance is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Could you recommend some learning materials for appmaker? You can find official documentation and resources available below so that you can start learning more about App Maker and the features available:

   - Official App Maker developer documentation https://developers.google.com/appmaker/
   - Official App Maker Templates which can give you a head start on different UI designs and useful application features https://developers.google.com/appmaker/templates/
   - Official App Maker Public Google Group https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/appmaker-users
   - App Maker office Hours YouTube Channel https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCnC9dI1zA-jkrPwOfeWmSJw/videos
   - Training resources and video tutorials created by one of Google Partners https://appmakeruniversity.com
   - App Maker video from Google Cloud Next '17 https://youtu.be/Br6aNwDXDgQ
   - App Maker video from Google I/O '17 https://youtu.be/Q84HQgI3Dd8
2. It seems that the there was no separated physical database for the app. How could I extra the data from the database? You can find information about importing and exporting data from App Maker here https://developers.google.com/appmaker/models/import-export
3. How could I monitor the requests going somewhere? I am not sure if I understood this last question. The best place to get support for App Maker is via this Stackoverflow tag or via the official App Maker Google Group provided above. You can also contact G Suite Support for any issues with the App Maker service.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hello, Wilmar, thank you so much for your information. It is very helpful. Thank you. For my last question, since I am using the document approval template,  for example, several people have filled in the information, some are in the draft status, some are in the approval process, some are already approved. As the administrator, where could I see all the information and workflow except to export the data all the time?